# Configuração do Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Tenho um projeto [android](/questions/tagged/android) criado no [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse). Neste projeto na tabela de *Problems* tenho alguns *warmings* (907) como mostra na figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como percebemos, consta desta forma:

> 0 errors, 907 warnings, 0 others (Filter matched 100 of 907 items)

Utilizo o [Eclipse Mars 2](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Mars/2), e gostaria de saber se tem como configura-lo para mostrar mais que 100 itens na lista de *Problems*? Se sim, como?

Exemplo: **(Filter matched 200 of 907 items)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para mudar o número de itens exibidos nesse grid, primeiro click com o botão esquerdo na seta para baixo no canto inferior direito.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acesso menu `Configure Contents`, na caixa de configura que aparecer olhe na parte de inferior, altere o item `Number of items visibles per group`. Para confirmar as alterações de OK.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]